# about number of failed ssh logins in ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

about 10 days ago i use this command to find out failed ssh logins on my ubuntu server :

```
grep -o -i 'Failed password' /var/log/auth.log | wc -l
```

and the answer was :

```
55371
```

and today i check that again and the answer is :

```
23110
```

it seems somebody tried to hack me but What happened to the server logs? why failed logins decreased?

Comment: i forgot to say the 'last' command shows my ip addresses only and seems nobody logged in except my self

Comment: Because ... `auth.log` is rotated weekly?

Comment: how can i find out 'auth.log' is set to rotate daily or weekly or monthly ?

Comment: in /etc/logrotate.conf :                                          # see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

Comment: `ls -l /var/log/auth*` should give you something like `auth.log`, `auth.log.1`, `auth.log.2.gz`, auth.log.3.gz`, and `auth.log.4.gz`.  If you want to review your old logs, you still have them (until they get really old).

Comment: "it seems somebody tried to hack me" -- usually botnets, an ubiquitous hazard of exposing services to the dystopic nightmare which is today's internet. I hope you have password logins disabled ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server logs are rotated and archived on per-determined intervals. Nothing bad happened to you logs. There are there, but archived.

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/log/auth.log*
```

Comment: Shouldn't need `sudo` here. The globbing pattern would not be expanded as root in any case.  Also note that the user isn't using `sudo` at all in their command to look inside the `auth.log` file.